# block all cookies flag in node js

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, flags, brave

can anyone know the name of the flag that I can include in args: in puppeteer that will block all cookies on the site

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        executablePath: 'C:/Program Files/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Application/brave.exe',
        slowMo: 100,
        headless: false,
        devtools: false,
        args: ['--disable-features=CookiesWithoutSameSiteMustBeSecure'],
    })
```

I found one, but unfortunately it does not work, maybe there is another way